# How to solve aggregation JSON documents

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, aggregate, aggregation

For every `source_website_link`, I want to find how many documents it has in MongoDB. I'm trying using aggregation.

sample of the documents:

```
{  "_id": {    "$oid": "6267f7eb400acbfb06b3d9d2"  },  "source_website_link": "https://16chan.xyz/k/",  "url_domains": [    {      "domain": "myminifactory.com",      "url": "https://www.myminifactory.com/object/3d-print-m18a1-claymore-72900"    }  ],  "created_at": {    "$date": {      "$numberLong": "1572493939000"    }  },  "post_text": "Grab the models while you can boys. Jews everywhere. Print all you can, blow up your local field offices. Rough af out there fr fr.\r https://www.myminifactory.com/object/3d-print-m18a1-claymore-72900",  "post_page": "https://16chan.xyz/k/6.html",  "id": "179",  "entity": 2}
{  "_id": {    "$oid": "6267f7f0400acbfb06b3d9d3"  },  "source_website_link": "https://neinchan.com/pol/",  "url_domains": [    {      "domain": "edition.cnn.com",      "url": "https://edition.cnn.com/2022/03/23/opinions/boris-romantschenko-russia-strike-death-wagner/index.html"    },    {      "domain": "townhall.com",      "url": "https://townhall.com/columnists/patbuchanan/2022/03/25/is-victory-for-ukraine-worth-risking-nuclear-war-n2605013"    },    {      "domain": "upi.com",      "url": "https://www.upi.com/Voices/2022/03/22/ukraine-Ukraine-women-fighters-feminism-Russia/5981647950000/"    }  ],  "created_at": {    "$date": {      "$numberLong": "1648420045000"    }  },  "post_text": "I am fishmilk the seal, and I have arrived to neinchan to give you all sorts of pills and happenings. Today's subject, a very Jewish war.\n\n>Happening the First: Jew kills another Jew. How sad. https://edition.cnn.com/2022/03/23/opinions/boris-romantschenko-russia-strike-death-wagner/index.html\n>Happening the Second: Yeah guys we should launch a destructive nuclear war against all superpowers so Ukraine can win a pointless war. https://townhall.com/columnists/patbuchanan/2022/03/25/is-victory-for-ukraine-worth-risking-nuclear-war-n2605013\n>Happening the Third: Women fighting in pointless wars is the peak of heritage in traditon.\nhttps://www.upi.com/Voices/2022/03/22/ukraine-Ukraine-women-fighters-feminism-Russia/5981647950000/",  "post_page": "https://neinchan.com/pol/index.html",  "id": "1569",  "entity": 2}
{  "_id": {    "$oid": "6267f7f0400acbfb06b3d9d4"  },  "source_website_link": "https://neinchan.com/pol/",  "url_domains": [    {      "domain": "boomtown.top",      "url": "https://boomtown.top/"    }  ],  "created_at": {    "$date": {      "$numberLong": "1647272134000"    }  },  "post_text": "Come funpost at https://boomtown.top/",  "post_page": "https://neinchan.com/pol/index.html",  "id": "1559",  "entity": 2}
```

So, the output should be that `https://16chan.xyz/k/` has one document and `https://neinchan.com/pol/` has two documents.

Using the following code:

```
@staticmethod
    def results_chans_aggregation():
        """
        Retrieve Chans sites statistics (e.g. Posts, URLs, etc...)
        """

        match_ = {
                     "$match": {
                         # "created_at": {"$gte": datetime.datetime.today() - timedelta(hours=2400)}
                         "created_at": {"$gte": datetime.today()}
                     }
                 },
        group_ = {
                     "$group": {
                         "_id": {"source_website_link": "$source_website_link"},
                         "Count": {"$sum": 1},
                     }
                 },
        sort_ = {
            "$sort": {"Count": 1}
        }

        chans_results = PyMongoCollections.chans.aggregate([match_, group_, sort_])
        chans_results = list(chans_results)

        return chans_results
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: Expected 'pipeline' to be BSON docs (or equivalent), but got primitive.A instead. Doc = [{aggregate message} {pipeline [[[{$match [{created_at [{$gte 1653996927570}]}]}]] [[{$group [{_id [{source_website_link $source_website_link}]} {Count [{$sum 1}]}]}]] [{$sort [{Count 1}]}]]} {cursor []} {lsid [{id {4 [255 54 73 10 158 141 71 48 165 254 54 14 164 253 25 34]}}]} {$clusterTime [{clusterTime {1653986130 2}} {signature [{hash {0 [72 100 96 218 98 126 69 140 205 232 14 101 60 98 132 64 80 95 132 46]}} {keyId 7051611631674982402}]}]} {$db ExTrac_Chat_DB} {$readPreference [{mode primary}]}], full error: {'ok': 0, 'errmsg': "Expected 'pipeline' to be BSON docs (or equivalent), but got primitive.A instead. Doc = [{aggregate message} {pipeline [[[{$match [{created_at [{$gte 1653996927570}]}]}]] [[{$group [{_id [{source_website_link $source_website_link}]} {Count [{$sum 1}]}]}]] [{$sort [{Count 1}]}]]} {cursor []} {lsid [{id {4 [255 54 73 10 158 141 71 48 165 254 54 14 164 253 25 34]}}]} {$clusterTime [{clusterTime {1653986130 2}} {signature [{hash {0 [72 100 96 218 98 126 69 140 205 232 14 101 60 98 132 64 80 95 132 46]}} {keyId 7051611631674982402}]}]} {$db ExTrac_Chat_DB} {$readPreference [{mode primary}]}]", 'code': 8000, 'codeName': 'AtlasError'}
```

Any thoughts on how to solve this?

Comment: The `},` at the end of each stage might be an issue.

Comment: @prasad_ But we can't do that without it. What do you think?

Comment: I suspect its syntax error. You can do this: `pipelien = [ { "$match": { ... } }, { "$group": { ...} }, { ... } ]` _and_ use the variable in the aggregation run: `result = list(collection.aggregate(pipeline))`

Answer (score 0):

This code might help you to get the  desired results.

```
@staticmethod
    def results_chans_aggregation():
        """
        Retrieve Chans sites statistics (e.g. Posts, URLs, etc...)
        """
Agr_Pipeline= [ { "$match": { "created_at": {"$gte": datetime.today()}} },
              { "$group": {"_id": {"source_website_link": "$source_website_link"},
                         "Count": {"$sum": 1} } },
              { "$sort": {"Count": 1}} ]

       
        
        chans_results = list(DBCOllection.aggregate(Agr_Pipeline))

        return chans_results
```